# How to run Serverspec tests as shared behaviors on multiple servers

Tags: serverspec

I tried to run Serverspec tests as shared behaviors on multiple servers by referencing from
http://serverspec.org/advanced_tips.html
When running test, I got the "No examples Found" message every times.
 How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution? I'm working on this too. Would you like to collaborate?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using test kitchen ,you can create a helpers directory and place all you shared behaviours in there,an example can be found [here](https://github.com/coderanger/shared-spec-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example:
http://artplustech.com/automated-infrastructure-testing-with-serverspec/

It is quite complex because it shows the power of writing customized tests for specific apps installed on the infrastructure, which depends on the evironment.